# How to properly config track_functions

Tags: postgresql

```
localhost:5432 admin@test=# set track_functions to 'all';
SET
localhost:5432 admin@test=# SELECT pg_reload_conf();
+----------------+
| pg_reload_conf |
+----------------+
| t              |
+----------------+
(1 row)

localhost:5432 admin@test=# \c -
psql (15beta1 (Ubuntu 15~~devel~20220516.2230-1~803.git05a5a17.pgdg20.04+1), server 14.3 (Ubuntu 14.3-1.pgdg20.04+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
You are now connected to database "test" as user "admin".
localhost:5432 admin@test=# show track_functions ;
+-----------------+
| track_functions |
+-----------------+
| none            |
+-----------------+
(1 row)
```

After I reconnect, the track_function return to `none`. How to config set it to `all` all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` only changes the value for the current session. It is lost when you disconnect. If you want to persist the change across sessions (and Postgres restarts) you need to use ALTER SYSTEM:

```
alter system set track_functions to 'all';
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```